# jQuery control animation

Tags: jquery

Hi guys I have the following code and and I want it to last for a certain time then the ".cta" should go back to its original position. Any ideaS?

```
$('.cta').delay(1000).animate ({left: '5'}, 800)
```

Thank you

Comment: it needs to stay with "left:5" for 4 seconds and then go back to "left:82"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){
        $('.cta').animate ({left: '5'}, 800,).delay(4000).animate ({left: '82'};
},1000);
```